# Feasibility of sub-file locking in PHP

Tags: php, database, locking

I try to find some simple, portable way of concurrent database access.

I have all data in single file. All records have same length.

My anti-deadlock strategy is specifying list of ids upfront then sort them from low to high (numerically) and then lock appropriate records (or block/wait if some record is already locked). Locking will be done by setting 'lock-byte' in each individual record. That way deadlocks should be impossible.

So pseudo code will be like :

```
    willLockId 2
    willLockId 1
    willLockId 3
    sortIds

    fopen db

    flock db EX_LOCK
    lockSortedIds // blocks and waits if someone already locked some id I want to use
    flock db UNLOCK

    // do my stuff ...

    flock db EX_LOCK
    unlockSortedIds
    fflush db
    flock db UNLOCK

    fclose db
```

I want to ask if this approach is good idea in general (did I horribly overlooked something?) and if it will stand performance-wise (read/write buffers should probably be turned off for this).

I didn't seen this method used anywhere, so I better ask.

Comment: Why not use an actual database server..?

Comment: I would like to stay light on dependencies and have it somewhat optimized for perfomance. .. so yeah my question is probably very about performance of this.

Comment: Off-the-shelf databases have sophisticated locking mechanisms, like single-writer-multi-reader, separate index and data locks, row-level locks, etc. And many other optimizations for storage and processing. If you need such mission critical performance that you need to write your own custom database code then probably a scripting language is not the best choice anyway... sorry for not answering your question (I'm not sure I fully understand your algorithm), but anyway, I believe that in 99 out of 100 cases (at least) a personal database implementation is not the best option...

Comment: You might find it useful to look at [flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), but be aware that every script that uses the file must use `flock()` or it won't work.

Comment: obe: I undertand what you say. PHP is not by far best for this, but is now a viable way. I try to find out how to write simple online games on shared web hosting. Off-the-shelves seems to be a bit overkill - I mostly need to change few bytes here and there - no indexing or queries needed.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular Thanks for hint .. actually I use flock already.